# How to sum every items in javascript

Tags: arrays, node.js, sorting, arraylist

I have an array like this:

```
items ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

I want to know how to get results like this:

```
A = 2 item (s);
B = 1 item (s);
C = 3 item (s);
```

does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as @Hakan Akin, different syntax

```js
const count = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
  .reduce((tmp, x) => ({
    ...tmp,
    
    [x]: (tmp[x] || 0) + 1,
  }), {});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

```
items.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1, prev), {})
```

And this returns

```
Object {A: 2, B: 1, C: 3}
```

Comment: You are welcome Deni :)